# make a private github repo via the command line

Tags: api, github

I want to be able to make a private github repo via the commandline. I think this should be possible using the rest API however I can't figure out how to do it from the docs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) tool [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) does have a `--private` option.

So, from the current directory of your local repository:

```
~/Projects/my-project$ gh repo create myNewRepo --private --source=.
```

An interactive creation would be:

```
~/Projects/my-project$ gh repo create
```

It would include:

```yaml
? Visibility  [Use arrows to move, type to filter]
  Public
> Private
  Internal
```

Comment: On Windows when I run `gh repo create --private` it says `name argument required to create new remote repository` and shows the command help.

Comment: @User True, I have fixed the answer, and completed it with an interactive option.