# GitHub create new repository (msg "remote: Repository not found")

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

When I want to simply create the remote private repository on GitHub from my local existing repository by git commands.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/"UserName"/"NameRemoteRepository".git
git push -u origin main
```

I received the error message:

> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/"UserName"/"NameRemoteRepository".git/' not found.

I check the same by SourceTree, change the type authentication on PAS, clean the Windows credentials and so on but result was the same (and I remember it's works early at September 2021).

**UPDATED:**
In the last case I met with problem - the repository was created on GitHub (by SourceTree) but I can't push to it the existed branch from local (main/master or other). See **updated** workaround

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution (at April 2022).
You must create the "NameRemoteRepository" repository on GitHub by GitHub WEB interface ("New" from "Your repositories") or by [GitHub CLI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398441/10951191) **before** you will run the command `git push -u origin main`

P.S>
Latter i found the mention of this fact on [GitHub forum](https://github.community/t/fatal-repository-not-found/1180/7) but doesn't found strong direction of that in Git or SourceTree documentation.

**UPDATED:**
I found that the main problem is the creation of new branch on GitHub (from local branch).
And I use the another Workaround for this problem. You can install on computer the GitHub Desktop, which haven't this limitation in creation on GitHub the new branch from local (and after creation return to the preferred tool).